# How To Connect To JanusGraph In Java with AnonymousTraversalSource

Tags: docker-container, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, gremlin-java

## Problem

Why am I unable-to-connect to JanusGraph-Server on `localhost:8182`? 
Using [Java-17](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/09/java-17-and-intellij-idea/), [TinkerPop3  Gremlin](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/), and [Janusgraph:latest](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/installation/#running-janusgraph-inside-a-docker-container).

## Reproduction

### Steps

1. Download-and-Install [Docker (Windows)](https://hub.docker.com/r/janusgraph/janusgraph)
2. Create-and-Startup JanusGraph Docker-container [`docker run -it -p 8182:8182 janusgraph/janusgraph`](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/installation/)
   [image: Gremlin running on Docker-container of Janusgraph-image]
3. Create-and-Run Java-Maven Project
4. Results

   1. Expected: No errors and that the rest of the code runs
   2. Actual: Runtime Error: `IllegalStateException`
      [image: Could not establish serializer - org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0]

### Logs

```bash
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteConnection.from(RemoteConnection.java:73)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.withRemote(AnonymousTraversalSource.java:76)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.withRemote(AnonymousTraversalSource.java:66)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteConnection.from(RemoteConnection.java:71)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not establish serializer - org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection.<init>(DriverRemoteConnection.java:84)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not establish serializer - org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster.getBuilderFromSettings(Cluster.java:228)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster.build(Cluster.java:173)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster.open(Cluster.java:265)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection.<init>(DriverRemoteConnection.java:80)
    ... 9 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

### Code

```
│   pom.xml
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │       Main.java
│   │   │
│   │   └───resources
│   │       │   log4j2.xml
│   │       │
│   │       ├───conf
│   │       │       remote-graph.properties
│   │       │       remote-objects.yaml
```

#### `Main.java`

```java
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;

import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote("src/main/resources/conf/remote-graph.properties");
    }
}
```

#### `remote-graph.properties`

```
gremlin.remote.remoteConnectionClass=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection
gremlin.remote.driver.clusterFile=src/main/resources/conf/remote-objects.yaml
gremlin.remote.driver.sourceName=g
```

###`remote-objects.yaml`

```yaml
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8182
serializer: {
  className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0,
  config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
```

#### `pom.xml`

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4-20230429-020227.dc3f877</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

## Update

Thanks Marc! This did fix my issue!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`remote-objects.yaml`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-examples/example-remotegraph/conf/remote-objects.yaml) for [`janusgraph-0.6.3`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v0.6.3) reads as follows (with a different version for the serializer):

```yaml
    hosts: [localhost]
    port: 8182
    serializer: {
        className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0,
        config: {ioRegistries:[org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry]}
    }
```

[Edited after comments]
[`janusgraph-1.0.0.rc2`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc2) reads:

```yaml
    hosts: [localhost]
    port: 8182
    serializer: {
        className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1, 
        config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }
    }
```

Your java project uses [`janusgraph-1.0.0.rc2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core/1.0.0-20230428-082704.5159135) while the gremlin server in the Docker container uses [`janusgraph-0.6.3`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core/0.6.4-20230429-020227.dc3f877) ([`latest`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/janusgraph/janusgraph/latest/images/sha256-c248f8d84430e775c54cb5fbcf560d72b9e6f737a2289fe9d048d290760ed2bf?context=explore) does not include [release candidates](https://hub.docker.com/layers/janusgraph/janusgraph/1.0.0-rc2/images/sha256-3735d6484b571327f50395b54ce7ea7fe9036663c1ebe68f63328bf1a0dc981a?context=explore)). Generally, you cannot mix minor versions for gremlin-driver and gremlin server.

Comment: This looks the same as my `remote-objects.yaml` except using [`GryoMessageSerializerV3d0`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.4.6/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/ser/GryoMessageSerializerV3d0.html) instead of [`GryoMessageSerializerV1d0`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.2.9/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/ser/GryoMessageSerializerV1d0.html).

Comment: And, TinkerPop3 seems to have Deprecated this [`GryoMessageSerializerV3d0`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.4.6/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/ser/GryoMessageSerializerV3d0.html) in place of [`GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.4.6/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/ser/GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1.html)

Comment: I tried these btw, and they didn't change the error

Comment: So ther error now reads: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not establish serializer - org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser. **GryoMessageSerializerV3d0** ?

Comment: Yes `Could not establish serializer - org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0`

Comment: OK, I did not notice the 1.0.0.rc2 version before, see the edits in the answer.