# Connecting To JanusGraph Using Java

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, docker-container, janusgraph, java-17

## Problem

How do you get [`Connecting to JanusGraph > Using Java`](https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/interactions/connecting/java/) to work? 
[`Connecting to JanusGraph Using Java` = `Connecting from Java` = `Getting Started with JanusGraph and Gremlin-Java`](https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/interactions/connecting/java/) in this question. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is with:

1. Docker-Image: janusgraph/janusgraph:latest 2023-04-11
2. SDK: corretto-17 "17.0.7"
3. Maven: 3.8.1

## Reproduction

### [Steps](https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/interactions/connecting/java/)

1. [Download and Install Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/janusgraph/janusgraph)
2. [Startup a JanusGraph Docker-container](https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/getting-started/installation/)

   ```bash
   $ docker run -it -p 8182:8182 janusgraph/janusgraph
   ```
3. Copy-Paste into CMD terminal

   ```bash
   mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.project
       -DartifactId=gremlin-example
       -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
       -DinteractiveMode=false
   ```

   1. PowerShell doesn't work on Guide-Step-1 without adding quotation-marks
4. Open Project in IDE

   1. e.g. IntelliJ
5. Upsert Maven Packages for JanusGraph and Gremlin-Driver

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
       <artifactId>janusgraph-driver</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0-rc2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
       <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
       <version>3.6.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   1. Guide-Step-2 at time of recording
6. Create-and-Add `conf/remote-graph.properties` and `conf/remote-objects.yaml`

   ```bash
   gremlin.remote.remoteConnectionClass=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection
   gremlin.remote.driver.clusterFile=conf/remote-objects.yaml
   gremlin.remote.driver.sourceName=g
   ```

   ```js
   hosts: [localhost]
   port: 8182
   serializer: { 
       className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1,
       config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
   ```
7. Update `App.main` with `GraphTraversalSource`

   ```java
   import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
   import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;
   public class App {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
           // Reuse 'g' across the application
           // and close it on shut-down to close open connections with g.close()
           Object herculesAge = g.V().has("name", "hercules").values("age").next();
           System.out.println("Hercules is " + herculesAge + " years old.");
           g.close();
       }
   }
   ```
8. Run Project

### Results

#### Expected

[Program would run and printout Hercules's age](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/basic-usage/).

#### Actual

Runtime Exception Error.

```bash
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: The traversal source [g] for alias [g] is not configured on the server.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:413)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:2118)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet.one(ResultSet.java:123)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.hasNext(ResultSet.java:175)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:182)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:169)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:115)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:100)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal.nextTraverser(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:92)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.processNextStart(RemoteStep.java:80)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:135)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:40)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.next(DefaultTraversal.java:249)
    at com.mycompany.project.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: The traversal source [g] for alias [g] is not configured on the server.
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:245)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:200)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinSaslAuthenticationHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:126)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinSaslAuthenticationHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.Utf8FrameValidator.channelRead(Utf8FrameValidator.java:89)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

[image: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: The traversal source [g] for alias [g] is not configured on the server.]

## Tried

1. Executing Guide.Step.1 PowerShell

   1. Results in `BUILD FAILURE` for Maven
2. Changing `conf` folder locations

   1. Runtime Exception Error: `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationException: Could not locate: FileLocator [basePath=null, encoding=ISO-8859-1, fileName=conf/remote-graph.properties, fileSystem=null, locationStrategy=null, sourceURL=null, urlConnectionOptions=null]`
3. Running [Local Installation JanusGraph](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases) on Windows with git-bash shell

   1. No change in error

```
│   pom.xml
│   
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   └───com
│   │   │       └───mycompany
│   │   │           └───project
│   │   │                   App.java
│   │   │
│   │   └───resources
│   │       └───conf
│   │               remote-graph.properties
│   │               remote-objects.yaml
```

Comment: Does the graph have the data (pre)loaded? If you change the `next` to `toList` do you at least get an empty list back?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence No I seem to only have got that on a fluke. Just tried to reopen and run the project and getting the same error about gremlin traversal again now.

Comment: Even with `toList` instead of `next` ? If the graph is empty, `next` will not return anything. `toList` will give you an empty list.

Comment: Both are giving me this error message now...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3-Part Problem: JanusGraph Container, Data Does Not Exist, and JanusGraph Example Does Not Load Data.

1. Delete JanusGraph container and remake a new one

   1. JanusGraph-Server is in a bad-state, as noted by GitHub-Issues: [`#1826`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1826) and [`#2868`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/2868)
2. Load Data in

   1. I don't know where JanusGraph's `Graph Of The Gods` data is saved
   2. [D3.js's `Graph Of The Gods`](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/faunus/blob/master/data/graph-of-the-gods.json) is pretty barebones

      1. And JanusGraph doesn't readily give an explanation of their import method
   3. JanusGraph does not start with data like Neo4j, OrientDB, or ArcadeDB
3. [JanusGraph documentation does not have preloaded nor steps-to-load this data in for their example](https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/interactions/connecting/java/)

## Update

Here's an example loading into JanusGraph with `AnonymousTraversalSource`.

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.TraversalSource;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversal;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Transaction;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;

import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
        Transaction tx = g.tx();
        tx.open();
        Vertex v1 = g.addV("person").property("name","marko").next();
        Vertex v2 = g.addV("person").property("name","stephen").next();
        g.V(v1).addE("knows").to(v2).property("weight",0.75).iterate();
        tx.commit();
        logger.info(g.V().count().next());
        g.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `GraphOfTheGodsFactory` class holds the data. So you can do things like `GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(graph)` - the source code for it is [here](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java) and the documentation is [here](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/basic-usage/)

Comment: Bummer, that's still going to make me need to setup a in-between storage-backend. This is what I've been trying to avoid dipping my toes in.

Comment: Yes, unless you can live with in-memory for dev/test/learning, at least as far as JanusGraph goes, you will need to setup some sort of storage backend. The quickest way I have found is to use a single node of Cassandra running out of the Cassandra docker image. That's pretty quick to setup. It really depends on what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: Say I just want to import with `g.V().addV()` instead, so I'm using just `AnonymousTraversalSource`. [How do I get past `Could not establish serializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76131305/how-to-connect-to-janusgraph-in-java-with-anonymoustraversalsource)?