# Connect to External JanusGraph Server With JanusGraphFactory

Tags: configuration-files, janusgraph, java-17, gremlin-server, graph-traversal

## Problem

How do you connect to an external [JanusGraph Server](https://docs.janusgraph.org/operations/server/) with [JanusGraphFactory](https://docs.janusgraph.org/operations/configured-graph-factory/)? 
I don't know what I'm doing and new to JanusGraph and Graph-Databases in-general. 
What is the [`JanusGraph > Configuration > "storage.backend"`](https://docs.janusgraph.org/configs/configuration-reference/#storage) property supposed to be to connect?

```bash
│   pom.xml
│
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │       Main.java
│   │   │
│   │   └───resources
│   │       │   log4j2.xml
│   │       │
│   │       ├───conf
│   │       │       remote-graph.properties
│   │       │       remote-objects.yaml
```

I've tried switching through the storage-backends' names `shorthands: berkeleyje, cql, hbase, inmemory`. 
And I expected at least one of them to work. 
But nothing seems to actually change it using the external JanusGraph-Server instance.

```java
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.BaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new BaseConfiguration();
        configuration.setProperty("storage.backend", "inmemory");
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.open(configuration);
        GraphTraversalSource g = janusGraph.traversal();
        logger.info(g.V().next());
        janusGraph.close();
    }
}
```

`remote-graph.properties`

```js
gremlin.remote.remoteConnectionClass=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection
gremlin.remote.driver.clusterFile=src/main/resources/conf/remote-objects.yaml
gremlin.remote.driver.sourceName=g
```

`remote-objects.yaml`

```js
hosts: [localhost]
port: 18182
serializer: {
  className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0,
  config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
```

`pom.xml`

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-inmemory</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-20230427-155952.3f229ac</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The JanusGraph-Server I'm using is a [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/janusgraph/janusgraph): 
`docker run -it -p 18182:8182 janusgraph/janusgraph`. 
Its [Gremlin-Server's Console](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/installation/) is the standard TCP-Port:8182 exposed on TCP-Port:18182. 
What do you do to connect to the external JanusGraph-Server?

```java
java.lang.Throwable: Hook creation trace
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.<init>(StandardJanusGraph.java:250) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:176) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:147) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:127) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240.jar:?]
    at Main.main(Main.java:14) [classes/:?]
2023-05-01 10:36:13,446 [DEBUG] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::   Caffeine vertex cache size: requested=20000 effective=20000 (min=100)
2023-05-01 10:36:13,448 [DEBUG] [o.j.g.t.v.CaffeineVertexCache.main] ::  Created dirty vertex map with initial size 32
2023-05-01 10:36:13,450 [DEBUG] [o.j.g.t.v.CaffeineVertexCache.main] ::  Created vertex cache with max size 20000
2023-05-01 10:36:13,455 [DEBUG] [o.j.g.t.JanusGraphBlueprintsGraph.main] ::  Created new thread-bound transaction standardjanusgraphtx[0x79c5636f]
2023-05-01 10:36:13,466 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.next(DefaultTraversal.java:257)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
2023-05-01 10:36:13,498 [DEBUG] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.pool-5-thread-1] ::   MessagePuller configured with ReadMarker timestamp slightly ahead of read lag time; waiting for the clock to catch up
```

[image: Hook creation trace at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph]

---

## Updates

### Update 1

No known way to directly connect to JanusGraph. 
Seems like [there should be a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76131305/how-to-connect-to-janusgraph-in-java-with-anonymoustraversalsource) with [`AnonymousTraversalSource`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/AnonymousTraversalSource.html) 
But no example presented-or-found.

### Update 2

[Setting-up JanusGraph with another backend-server on Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76155697/how-to-setup-janusgraph-cassandra-on-docker) 
Seems to be the only viable on a Windows machine, in this case [Apache Cassandra](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra) is being used.
Need to manually add [`janusgraph-cql.properties`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-dist/src/assembly/cfilter/conf/janusgraph-cql.properties) for [Cassandra-JanusGraph](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#dockercass), which is only found in [`janusgraph/janusgraph-dist/src/assemnbly/cfilter/conf/`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/tree/master/janusgraph-dist/src/assembly/cfilter/conf) and can be pulled from [its ZIP Releases](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases).

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=cql
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
storage.cql.keyspace=janusgraph
storage.cql.local-datacenter=datacenter1
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
```

This is copy-pasted into the Cassandra-Docker-container.

```bash
docker exec -i jg-cassandra mkdir -p /opt/janusgraph/conf
docker cp janusgraph-cql.properties jq-cassandra:/opt/janusgraph/conf
```

Running the code again, returns this error now.

[image: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager]

Notable Logging:

```bash
[INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
[DEBUG] [c.d.o.d.i.c.u.Reflection.main] ::   Could not load com.esri.core.geometry.ogc.OGCGeometry with loader null: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esri.core.geometry.ogc.OGCGeometry
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esri.core.geometry.ogc.OGCGeometry
    ... 
    at Main.main(Main.java:6) [classes/:?]
```

```bash
2023-05-02 12:20:19,310 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.c.ControlConnection.JanusGraph Session-admin-1] ::   [JanusGraph Session] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=34665a95), trying next node
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [JanusGraph Session|control|id: 0x5cf58f41, L:/127.0.0.1:58140 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer)
... 
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer
```

```bash
[WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.c.ControlConnection.JanusGraph Session-admin-1] ::   [JanusGraph Session] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=ef8c065), trying next node
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [JanusGraph Session|control|id: 0xea4dcd74, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:58141 - R:localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer)
...
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer
```

```bash
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 2 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=34665a95): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [JanusGraph Session|control|id: 0x5cf58f41, L:/127.0.0.1:58140 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer)], Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=ef8c065): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [JanusGraph Session|control|id: 0xea4dcd74, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:58141 - R:localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer)]
...
    Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer
    Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [JanusGraph Session|control|id: 0xea4dcd74, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:58141 - R:localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer)
...
    Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer
```

```bash
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager
...
    Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Just to get you up and running, does [any of this](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#janusintro) help?

Comment: I can't use `inmemory` because I'm working with datasets larger than a GB: [ICIJ-Offshoreleaks-data-packages](https://github.com/ICIJ/offshoreleaks-data-packages/blob/eabbabfeaf1983c2b83c11125802fcdeda92d9ac/data/icij-offshoreleaks-44.dump) and [Lung-Cancer Graph-Database](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/RIXLG8)

Comment: Understood but in terms of basic configuration - have you also deployed a storage backend such as Cassandra alongside the graph? Janus will not automatically deploy, say, Cassandra for you. You need to have it already up and running. As discussed [here](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#dockercass)

Comment: So I need Cassandra or some other one of those options to connect to JanusGraph?

Comment: Yes - or get it working with in-memory first to iron out any other issues, and once that is working progress to getting a persistent storage backend working.

Comment: Where's the [`janusgraph-cassandra.properties` from your example](https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/janus-cassandra.groovy)?

Comment: It's in the `/conf` folder but has since been renamed to `janusgraph-cql.properties`.

Comment: I don't see the folder, can you provide a link, please?

Comment: It's part of the standard JanusGraph distribution, alongside `../bin` there will be a `../conf`

Comment: Ah, only inside the [`janusgraph-0.6.3.zip`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v0.6.3), not its docker-container

Comment: I would have expected it to be in both places, but your code will need access to it either way. You should be able to mount the container volumes (-v) in such a way that the files are visible to your application code.

Comment: Where in the docker-container is `janusgraph-cassandra.properties` supposed to be dropped-in? 
I don't see the `conf` directory in `/etc/opt/janusgraph/`, `/tmp/hsperfdata_janusgrpah`, or `/var/lib/janusgraph/`

Comment: For now I would just copy it from GitHub and make sure your application can access it from your local file system. https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/tree/master/janusgraph-dist/src/assembly/cfilter/conf

Comment: Inside the container the files are here `/opt/janusgraph/conf`

Comment: How do you fix `[c.d.o.d.i.c.a.AdminRequestHandler.JanusGraph Session-io-3] ::  [JanusGraph Session] Got response ERROR(unconfigured table peers_v2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is making a valid [`JanusGraph` instance](https://javadoc.io/static/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core/0.4.0/org/janusgraph/core/JanusGraph.html) from [`JanusGraphFactory` call](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core/0.4.0/org/janusgraph/core/JanusGraphFactory.html). 
Which is a bit of a misnomer on how [hard this is to find information on configuring `JanusGraphFactory` (at time of recording)](https://docs.janusgraph.org/configs/#janusgraphfactory).

[image: JanusGraphFactory Gremlin Console]

> ## JanusGraphFactory
>
> ### Gremlin Console
>
> The JanusGraph distribution contains a command line Gremlin Console which makes it easy to get started and interact with JanusGraph. Invoke bin/gremlin.sh (Unix/Linux) or bin/gremlin.bat (Windows) to start the Console and then open a JanusGraph graph using the factory with the configuration stored in an accessible properties configuration file:
>
> `graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('path/to/configuration.properties')`

This is what you'll need:

### Code

```
│   pom.xml
│   
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │       Main.java
│   │   │
│   │   └───resources
│   │       │   log4j2.xml
```

#### `Main.java`

```java
//import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory;
//import org.janusgraph.core.PropertyKey;
//import org.janusgraph.core.schema.JanusGraphManagement;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
//        JanusGraphManagement janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
//        PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getPropertyKey("_id");
//        janusGraphManagement.buildIndex("_id", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).buildCompositeIndex();
//        janusGraphManagement.commit();
        janusGraph.close();
    }
}
```

#### `log4j2.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="baseDir">logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/log-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                     filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%p] [%c{1.}.%t] ::&#x09; %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%p] [%c{1.}.%t] ::&#x09; %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

#### `pom.xml`

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-cql</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```